# DBeaver FATAL: database "myDb" does not exist. Ошибка при создании новой БД

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

Столкнулся с проблемой создания новой базы postgres  через Dbeaver - FATAL: database "myDb" does not exist. При этом раньше все было нормально, попробовал удалить Posgres драйвер, он пропал из Dbeaver полностью, пришлось установить обратно вручную. Но проблема осталась [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создал базу через sql sell, вот что мне возвращает команда \conninfo - `You are connected to database "myDb" as user "postgres" on host "localhost" (address "::1") at port "5432".`

Comment: А вы уверены что существует база _myDb_?

Comment: а разве я не создаю ее как раз в этот момент через Dbeaver?

Comment: Возможно, после 10 утра сюда заглянет разработчик Dbeaver  и сможет вам помочь)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб кто он?!

Comment: @InDevX теперь точно уверен, создал ее через cmd. теперь пытаюсь создать connection через DBeaver, та же ошибка

Comment: @nörbörnën, а вот в ответе можно глянуть)

Answer (score 4):

День добрый.
Во-первых, на русский стаковерфлоу редко кто-то из команды заглядывает, зато мы оперативно отвечаем тут https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues и ещё тут https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/discussions

Во-вторых, расскажите, пожалуйста, как именно Вы пытались создать новую базу в Постгресе?
[image: создание базы постгрес]

У нас есть специальный инструмент создания новой базы в открытом соединении для Постгреса, возникает при клике в дереве на соединение.

Во-вторых, меня смущает на картинке то, как выглядит окно создания нового соединения. Серый значок в правом углу говорит о том, что окошко соединения не знает, к какой базе данных Вы хотите присоединиться, а значит не будет содержать важных полей для соединения именно с постгресом и не содержит информации о драйверах.
Чтобы создать новое соединение, в меню "Базы данных" и выбрать Постгрес.

[image: новый коннект к постгрес]

Comment: Добрый день, спасибо за обратную связь! Уже разобрался, проблема была не в Вашей программе, а видимо в самом Posеgres. Когда я создавал БД через Sql Shell, там был указан дефолтный хост localhost. Но я заметил что база там не создалась, поэтому я попробовал прописать хост 127.0.0.1 и база создалась, после этого удалось открыть соединение

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо за обратную связь :)